# Asp.net Identity - User not authenticated after successful login and redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an ASP.net webforms application created with a Visual Studio 2013 template so it uses Microsoft Identity for user authentication.

I recently moved this application to a new Rackspace Cloud Server running Windows Server 2012 R2. Since then, occasionally something happens that makes **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** always return false and the LoginStatus and LoginView controls display as if the user is not logged in. This occurs even after a successful login and redirect using the IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl helper.

As soon as I reset the application by saving the web.config file or re-publishing it from Visual Studio, the problem is solved. However, the problem always comes back an hour or so later.

Any ideas what could be causing this, or what else I can do to troubleshoot?

Comment: That sounds a little bit like this bug: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545850 but for a different server version

Comment: Yeah, a little, but other than using ApplicationPoolIdentity none of the other symptoms apply. I couldn't find a similar bug report or hotfix for 2012 R2 or IIS 8.

Comment: *I recently moved this application* - Where was the application hosted at previously?  Also, I can't help but think this is a cookie-related issue.

Comment: It was previously hosted on another Rackspace cloud server running Server 2012 (not R2) and less RAM. It seems to be happening more often at times when the server is under heavier traffic load from other applications on the same server.

Comment: @Joshua, yes it appears to be a cookie issue. There is usually a cookie named .AspNet.ApplicationCookie that shows up in the F12 tools in a normal login. When this problem occurs, that cookie is missing.

Comment: Well, are your cookies expiring?

Comment: No, the cookie isn't getting saved at all on the redirect after logging in.

Comment: so it's cookie issue ? because it also happen to me

Comment: I never really tracked down the cause of this problem. I moved the application to a new server and the problem went away, so I suspect it was a bug or something in that installation of IIS or the .NET framework.